# Trying to create shapekeys by moving verts

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

Hello I am trying to create shapekeys by moving verts instead of sculpting. When I go to do this I noticed the gizmo is set to the verts resting position instead of the new posed position. How can I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The gizmo appears at the origin of the object.
Always apply Transforms CTRL A before shape keys because its good to have Ref. points at 0 when starting.

For now, just SET ORIGIN to C.O.M at the object mode.

Comment: I applied all transforms and the vertices origin is still defaulting to the rest position even when setting the origin to center of mass. I can see when toggling off On Cage in the armature modifier that the verticies origin is sitting at the rest pose, it just won't move to the posed position when toggling On Cage on.

Comment: The vertices don't have an origin. Neail is right. I forgot about how the gizmo behaves because I don't even use the gizmo. But when I turned it back on, it did indeed stay at the object's origin, regardless of the vertex selections in Edit mode. But this doesn't matter. You don't need the gizmo to behave differently than it does to create shape keys based on vertex tweaks instead of using the sculpt brush. The gizmo position is immaterial. Do you have experience setting up shape keys? What happens when you ignore the gizmo and just go ahead and create them?

Comment: I can create them, it's just you lose the ability to move the verts exactly where you want correctly, easily. Also you lose the ability to snap the verts correctly to other verts. I was trying to match up the vert placement to a seperate mesh and with the gizmo being offset, the gizmo snaps but the vert continues being offset.